# Validate Image in .NET Core / ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, validation, asp.net-core

How can i check that an image being uploaded to my server is in fact a valid image?

I'm able to check the size and the extension but there's nothing stopping a user from changing the file extension of an unsupported file to something supported (.jpg or .png, for example).

I understand that ASP.NET had Drawing.Image for this but .NET Core seems to be lacking anything I can use.

Could I have some recommendations for third party solutions?

Comment: Are .jpg and .png the only supported formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install nuget Package `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` then you can use `System.Drawing` in your .Net Core project like old times:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks :)

Comment: @Braed You are welcome. I have already used it in two of my projects.

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance but how would I go about adding this to my project? It doesn't have a NuGet package and i'd require the .NET Core 2.0 version.

Comment: I have used it with .Net Core 1.1, but I'm not sure with its compatibility with .Net Core 2.0. Open Package Manager Console from Menu > Nuget Package Manager >  Package Manager Console. Then execute the command : `Install-Package CoreCompat.System.Drawing`

Comment: "Unable to find package 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing'"... They do have a 2.0 version.

Comment: This one installed properly, i'll see if i can get it to work. Thanks! https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2/5.2.0-preview1-r131

Comment: Nice. glad you shared it with me. I may need it in my next projects

Comment: I've answered my own question as I've explained what i did, but thank you again for the package reference.

Answer (score 2):

Using [CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2/5.2.0-preview1-r131) I have made a simple check for image validity as seen below. If the "image" can't be opened then it's corrupt or fake and will throw an exception which i'm catching.
I appreciate that try/catch shouldn't be used for validation or logic but this is the best solution I can think of.

```
try
{
    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());
}
catch
{
    // bad image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't validate the entire image, but you could check the first few bytes of the file to make sure it contains a valid [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) or [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) header. This will prevent all but a tiny fraction of users from uploading a fake image and prevent you from spending resources loading the whole image into memory to check it.

Comment: Great suggestion! I'm considering processing the image resolutions anyway but if i choose not to, i'll go with this. Cheers.